# Вывод данных с формы на страницу

Tags: php, html, html-form

Имеется форма записи `html` а также ее обработчик который заносит введенные данные в бд `mysql` и выводит на экран.

Данные вводятся в бд и выводится информация с формы на `html` страницу, но есть проблема с выводом информации с элемента select (выпадающий список), нужно чтобы выводилось выбранное слово, а не его код.

Форма записи

```
<form class="contact_form" action="message.php" method="post" name="contact_form">
        <br>
    <ul>
        <li>
             <h2>Введите данные для записи на прием</h2>
             <span class="required_notification">* Поля, обязательные для заполнения</span>
        </li>
        <li>
            <label for="name">Имя:</label>
            <input type="text" name="name" required placeholder="Ваше имя">
        </li>
         <li>
            <label for="surname">Фамилия:</label>
            <input type="text" name="surname" required placeholder="Ваша фамилия">
        </li>
        <li>
            <label for="middlename">Отчество:</label>
            <input type="text" name="middlename" required placeholder="Ваше отчество">
        </li>
        <li>
            <label for="policynumber">Номер полиса:</label>
            <input type="text" name="policynumber" required placeholder="Ваш номер полиса">
        </li>
        <li>
            <label for="doc">Выберите врача:</label>
            <select name="doctor">
        <option value="1" selected>Терапевт</option>
        <option value="2">Стоматолог</option>
            </select>
        </li>
        <li>
            <label for="dateofbirthr">Дата рождения:</label>
            <input type="date" name="dateofbirth" required placeholder="Дата рождения">
        </li>
        <li>
            <label for="dateofadmission">Выберите дату приема:</label>
            <input type="date" name="dateofadmission" required placeholder="Дата приема">
        </li>
        <li>
            <button class="submit" type="submit">Отправить</button>
        </li>
    </ul>
</form>
```

Обработчик формы (не стал его полностью копировать, пропустил момент с подключением к бд)

```
try {

        switch ($doctor) {
            case 1:
                $table = "therapist";
                break;
            case 2:
                $table = "dentist";
                break;
        }

        $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $dbh->beginTransaction();
        $sth = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO `$table` (name, surname, middlename, dateofbirth, policynumber, dateofadmission) VALUES (:name, :surname, :middlename, :dateofbirth, :policynumber, :dateofadmission)");

        // Для вставки параметров в запрос PDO есть специальные методы
        $sth->bindParam(':name', $name, PDO::PARAM_STR); 
        $sth->bindParam(':surname', $surname, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $sth->bindParam(':middlename', $middlename, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $sth->bindParam(':dateofbirth', $dateofbirth, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $sth->bindParam(':policynumber', $policynumber, PDO::PARAM_INT); 
        $sth->bindParam(':dateofadmission', $dateofadmission, PDO::PARAM_STR);

        $sth->execute();
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        $dbh->rollBack();
    }
    print (" Ваше имя: " . $_POST['name'] . ".<br>\n");
    print (" Ваша фамилия: " . $_POST['surname'] . ".<br>\n");
    print (" Ваше отчество: " . $_POST['middlename'] . ".<br>\n");
    print (" Дата рождения: " . $_POST['dateofbirth'] . ".<br>\n");
    print (" Номер полиса: " . $_POST['policynumber'] . ".<br>\n");
    print (" Дата приема: " . $_POST['dateofadmission'] . ".<br>\n");
    print (" Лечащий врач: " . $_POST['doctor'] . ".<br>\n");


    {
        $dbh->commit();
    }
}
?>
```

Вот что выводится на экран (обратите внимание на последнюю строку)[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Поменяйте value у селекта, либо сделайте switch в обработчеке

Comment: Ужасный код, не используйте `print` - используйте `echo` - данная конструкция поддерживает оператор `and so on` (и так далее), то есть `echo $a, $b, $c;` - перечисление аргументов через запятую, за место конкатенации `$a.$b.$c` и работает быстрее чем `print`. И рекомендую использовать `mysqli` с драйвером `mysqlnd`.

Answer (score 1):

У Вас все правильно выводится.

```
<select name="doctor">
    <option value="1" selected>Терапевт</option>  
    <option value="2">Стоматолог</option>
 </select>
 В данном случае значение $_POST['doctor'] будет 1 или 2 для того чтобы вывести профессию нужно написать вроде этого:
<select name="doctor">
    <option value="Терапевт" selected>Терапевт</option>  
    <option value="Стоматолог">Стоматолог</option>
 </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$posts = [
    1 => 'Терапевт', 
         'Стоматолог'
];

print (" Лечащий врач: " . $posts[$_POST['doctor']] . ".<br>\n");
```

Comment: Использовал этот вариант так как у меня какая то др. версия php  $posts = array(1 => 'Терапевт', 'Стоматолог');

Comment: @SergSKH вы передаете номер option'a, попробуйте лучше вариант который предложил Web Desg, работает куда логичнее и удобнее будет редактировать.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function selected() {
document.getElementsByClassName("text")[0].innerHTML = $("select").val();
  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="select" onclick="selected();" name="doctor">
            <option value="Терапевт" selected>Терапевт</option>
            <option value="2">Стоматолог</option>
</select>
<h1 class="text"></h1>
```

У вас в "value" значение 2(я добавил дополнительный JS код для демонстрации), при отправки формы это значение добавляется в вашу базу данных, поэтому когда вы выводите это, получаете цифру 2. Укажите в "value" именование врача.